# Pagination and infinite scrolling in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pagination, infinite-scroll

I'm using this plug in for my application https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless/blob/master/lib/jquery.pageless.js and I'm using the Solr's sunspot for my search functionality.
I'm new to rails and I've a problem which I cant get my head around. I have this code in my controller to fetch the data from solr's engine

```
             def first
                @init = Sunspot.search(Clothes) do
                paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 16
                order_by :maxprice
             end


             @first = @init.results

             if request.xhr?
               sleep(1)
               render :partial => 'shirts/first'
             end
```

Then I have this javascript code:

```
             $('#container1').pageless({ 
                totalPages: 5,
                url: 'shirts/first',
                loaderMsg: 'Loading more results'
             });
```

Now if I set totalPages parameter to 10 then I can scroll upto 10 pages even though there aren't any results. Can someone tell if there's any way I could set the parameter to its max value, so that it scrolls down only to number of pages it has to display?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go through this awesome railscasts by Ryan instead, exclusively for Rails

http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page

Answer (score 0):

You could set the max number of pages in your view and then use that parameter when calling pageless. Something like this:

```
var numPages = <%= @numPages %>;
$('#container1').pageless({ 
   totalPages: numPages,
   url: 'shirts/first',
   loaderMsg: 'Loading more results'
})
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I could set the value in the @numpages in the view page? Can you give me an example>?